# Can a derivative function be ugly like this?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that a derivative function must obey the Intermediate Value Theorem of Derivatives. If the picture below is a derivative function $f'$ of some real-valued function $f$ with real variable, then from the figure we can see $f'$ really satisfies it. However, is it true that this function is a derivative function of some function? PS: The picture is informally draw by hand, the left and right half curve can be viewed as a shape of part of parabola.
[image]

Comment: That function (or any function with a step discontinuity) does not satisfy the intermediate value property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that cannot be the graph of $f'$ for some differentiable function $f$. Observe that if you restrict your function to its central half, then you lose the intermadiate value property. Besides, that property means that if $y$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then $y=f(c)$ *for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$*. That's not the case even for your original function.